# Active Directory groups not immediately available after creation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory, directoryservices

I am creating Active Directory groups in my app. I make security and distribution groups. The groups will get created just fine, but it takes about 10-15 minutes to show up in the Active Directory Users and Computers.

*Is there some kind of forced sync I can perform in C# to make this happen sooner? Or maybe some setting I can change in my directory to change this behavior?*

**Example code**

```
        DirectoryEntry ou1= topLevel.Children.Find("OU=ou1");
        DirectoryEntry secGroups = ou1.Children.Find("OU=Security Groups");
        DirectoryEntry newGroup = secGroups.Children.Add("CN=" + name + "", "group");

        newGroup.CommitChanges();

        GroupPrincipal createdGroup = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(this._context, name);
        createdGroup.SamAccountName = name;
        createdGroup.DisplayName = name;            
        createdGroup.GroupScope = GroupScope.Universal;

        createdGroup.Save();

        if (members.Any())
        {
            foreach (var item in members)
            {
                createdGroup.Members.Add(this._context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, item);
            }
            createdGroup.Save();
        }
```

Using ASP.NET MVC, C#, System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement, System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.

Comment: Do you have multiple ADs?

Comment: Not sure if this will answer your question but we have several domains in this active directory. I don't think we have more than 1 active directory. (sorry this is still sort of new to me). Do you think it could be a replication issue?

Comment: Usually, there're at least 2 domain controllers (not every company)... And yes, I was leaning toward the replication delay...What kind of error do you get during that 10-15 min when you search for created group?

Comment: I don't get any errors per se. The code executes correctly (without an exception being thrown) But I have another program that runs every 30 minutes that essentially syncs the AD groups with a list of groups in our DB. It would look in AD and not see the new groups.

Comment: Most likely they are not getting replicated right away. To prove this, instead of specifying `yourdomain.com` when you create a `PrincipalContext` or `DirectoryEntry`, specify FQDN of the first domain controller and then see if it's returning. Then try with a different one. If in fact one will return the group, it's the delay in synching.

Comment: @Burzum and yes this was the issue. I set my ldap string to include the DC and it was there immediately. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most likely answer is that it takes time to propagate to all domain controllers on your network. You may be connected to a different DC via ADUC from the one your application updated.

Comment: Is there a way to set the DC in my LDAP string or principal context?

Comment: You can specify the same DC in both connections and check if this is the source of your issue.

Comment: Excellent. Changed my ldap string to include the DC and it worked right away. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Something that might help in this situation where you have multiple domain controllers replicating is to target a specific DC for each call you make to the AD server.

So instead of "LDAP://mydomain.com" it becomes something like "LDAP://myDC.mydomain.com"